# Django, adding on localhost in admin panel error but working when manually on db.sqlite3

Tags: django, database, admin, panel

Working on my first django website.
In the Admin panel on the local host unable to add anything simply by clicking add. Error added at the bottom. Manual change of db.sqlite3 with DB browser for SQLite is working fine.

Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\cex.virtualenvs\Web-IP9wVexr\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:  C:\Users\cex.virtualenvs\Web-IP9wVexr\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:
['C:\Localpath\Documents\Web',
 'C:\Localpath\.virtualenvs\Web-IP9wVexr\Scripts\python38.zip',
 'c:\Localpath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\DLLs',
 'c:\Localpath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib',
 'c:\Localpath\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32',
 'C:\Localpath\.virtualenvs\Web-IP9wVexr',
 'C:\Localpath\.virtualenvs\Web-IP9wVexr\lib\site-packages']

Comment: It seems you have not done the migration. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/)

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate done with no luck. tried  adding rfesh db file, diferent django version etc. #puzzeled

Comment: So the migration was done without error or you encountered some exception during the migration?

Comment: absolutely no error with migrations. On sqlite3 in tables all tables added and structure matching app models.py. the admin panel refuses to add data to tables via local host panel

Comment: if u can delete migration in app or all db.slite3 and do migrate again ::

Comment: i say if u can i mean the data if is' not  very important

Comment: tried, no success. the exception is pointing here, especially the last line     """Django uses "format" style placeholders, but pysqlite2 uses "qmark" style.
    This fixes it -- but note that if you want to use a literal "%s" in a query,
    you'll need to use "%%s".
    """
    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Comment: got no clue what does it have to do with admin panel                                                                                       Exception Location: django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)